# My mock is not being used by my program

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I have a program that I want to mock data for using Mockito.
My main program is `AdDataAggregate` and it calls `AdDataConnect`.
`AdDataConnect` makes a call to an API that returns a string that is parsed into JSON and aggregated.

I've created the mocks and they return data but they are not being used by the main program.
Can someone please show me the error of my ways.  Thanks in advance for your help.

```
//Main Program
public class AdDataAggregate {  
public List<AdData> processInfo(long[] adIds){         
    AdDataConnect adDataConnect = new AdDataConnect();         
    List<AdData> adAccumData = new ArrayList<AdData>();             

    for (long adId: adIds) {       
         data = adDataConnect.connectToData(adId);  <———— method  to Mock. 
        }          }
}     


//Test Program
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)     
public class AdDataTest {                  
@InjectMocks            
    private AdDataAggregate adDataAggregate = new AdDataAggregate();         
    @Mock
    private AdDataConnect adDataConnect;             
    private String oneAdId = 
             "[{\"advertiser_id\":\"1\",\"ymd\":\"2015-12-" + 
             "07\",\"num_clicks\":10,\"num_impressions\":100}," +                                       
             "{\"advertiser_id\":\"1\",\"ymd\":\"2015-12-" +
             "06\",\"num_clicks\":20,\"num_impressions\":200}," +     
             "{\"advertiser_id\":\"1\",\"ymd\":\"2015-12-" +
             "05\",\"num_clicks\":30,\"num_impressions\":300}]";  

     @Test    
    public void testWithOneAdId(){          
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        adDataConnect = mock(AdDataConnect.class);
        adDataAggregate = mock(AdDataAggregate.class);
        when(adDataConnect.connectToData(eq(1L))) .thenReturn(oneAdId);    
        String myString = adDataConnect.connectToData(1L);             
        long[] adIds = new long[]{1L};             
        List<AdData> outData = adDataAggregate.processInfo(adIds); 
        Assert.assertEquals(1, outData.size());             
        Assert.assertEquals(myString, oneAdId); 
        Assert.assertEquals(60, outData.get(0).getNumImpressions());             
        Assert.assertEquals(600, outData.get(0).getNumImpressions());              
    }         
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to inject the AdDataConnect into your AdDataAggregate instead of instantiating it. When you instantiate it from within AdDataAggregate you are forcing an implementation to be used. You need to allow someone from the outside to set it so that you can set the mocked version in your tests.

Here is how you do it. Pass the AdDataConnect in the constructor:

```
public class AdDataAggregate
{
    private AdDataConnect adDataConnect;

    public AdDataAggregate(AdDataConnect adDataConnect)
    {
        this.adDataConnect = adDataConnect;
    }

    public List<AdData> processInfo(long[] adIds)
    {
        List<AdData> adAccumData = new ArrayList<AdData>();
        for(long adId : adIds)
        {
            data = adDataConnect.connectToData(adId);
        }
    }
}
```

Then in your test do this. You can see my comment where I used the new constructor:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class AdDataTest
{
    private AdDataAggregate adDataAggregate;

    @Mock
    private AdDataConnect adDataConnect;

    private String oneAdId = "[{\"advertiser_id\":\"1\",\"ymd\":\"2015-12-"
            + "07\",\"num_clicks\":10,\"num_impressions\":100}," + "{\"advertiser_id\":\"1\",\"ymd\":\"2015-12-"
            + "06\",\"num_clicks\":20,\"num_impressions\":200}," + "{\"advertiser_id\":\"1\",\"ymd\":\"2015-12-"
            + "05\",\"num_clicks\":30,\"num_impressions\":300}]";

    @Test
    public void testWithOneAdId()
    {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        adDataAggregate = new AdDataAggregate(adDataConnect);//PASS THE MOCK HERE

        when(adDataConnect.connectToData(eq(1L))).thenReturn(oneAdId);
        String myString = adDataConnect.connectToData(1L);
        long[] adIds = new long[] { 1L };
        List<AdData> outData = adDataAggregate.processInfo(adIds);
        Assert.assertEquals(1, outData.size());
        Assert.assertEquals(myString, oneAdId);
        Assert.assertEquals(60, outData.get(0).getNumImpressions());
        Assert.assertEquals(600, outData.get(0).getNumImpressions());
    }
}
```

Comment: Great! Please accept my answer so I get credit. Thanks!